# Comparison of insertion sort and bubble sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, runtime, bubble-sort, insertion-sort

I am trying to find out the actual time taken by both these algorithms to execute and what I found was inconsistent with information on the internet in many places which says that insertion sort is better. I however found bubble sort was executing more quickly. My code was as follows.

#### Bubble sort

```
for(int j = 0; j < a.length - 1; j++){
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length - 1 - j; i++) {
        count++;
        if(a[i] > a[i+1]){
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[i + 1];
            a[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Insertion sort

```
for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++){  
    for(int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j-- ){   
        if(a[j] > a[i]) {
            temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[i];
            a[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

I calculated the start and end time as this.

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
.....your program....
long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
System.out.println(totalTime);
```

What I found was that for insertion sort average time for 10 runs came to be 13 and for bubble sort it came to be just 5. Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: That's not insertion sort. It's not even a sort: http://ideone.com/aFCPft

Comment: That insertion sort looks suspiciously like [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). You should read [Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) and implement that algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

You've implemented insertion sort wrong. The code that was supposed to be an insertion sort doesn't even sort the array; for example, trying it on the input

```
int a[] = {4, 2, 3, 1, 5};
```

gives the output

```
[2, 3, 1, 4, 5]
```

See a demo: http://ideone.com/aFCPft

Given that the code doesn't work, the timing data doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Sorry edited the code and now the results seem to comply with findings of others.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How many elements are you sorting?
Just to make sure no obscure constant costs are in the way I usually take like longint.max elements for these tests.
Also if you sort not enough elements it's possible that just at that time your CPU is busy for some reason. With more elements that error-source is less relevant.

But yes, sounds strange. Maybe there is some compiler-optimization for stupid loops that doesn't work for optimized loops?

Just out of curiosity: did you try with 32bit and 64bit application? The results may differ sometimes :O

Comment: Sure. You can go downwards from that point. But it should take more than just a few seconds. Something around 1 minute is representative for long calculations I think ;)